# Drag file from chrome browser to C# winform application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to get a url of a dragged item on winforms. It's not capturing.

The following code works for local applications dragging from local drive it captures location. But dragging from browser its preventing.

[Debug Image Click Here to See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJAv9.png)

Example I have a browser url http://example.com/image.jpg

When I tried to drag and drop unable to capture the link location of the file.

```
string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop,false);
        if(files != null && files.Length!=0)
        {
            wp_fetch_url.Text = files[0];
        }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and examine the DataFormat that you are getting. Is the drop event getting raised? It could be that you are receiving a url in text format.

Comment: Perhaps the browser doesn't pass it as a file, so `FileDrop` is most likely not applicable here.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Can you please look at updated question. I have attached debug image. How do I know what type of data source it is and how to work with it.

Comment: @Joey Can you please look at updated question. I have attached debug image. How do I know what type of data source it is and how to work with it.

Comment: You have to drill down further. Open Values and open the first Item in Values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] file = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
{
  if (Path.GetExtension(file[0]) == ".url")
  {
   wp_fetch_url.Text = file[0];
  }
 }
```

Comment: How does this gets location of the url dropped from the web browser?